# How to add <br> tag after all the header element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```html
<h1>Intro</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>Main part</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

I need to add a `<br>` element after each heading.

Expected output:

```html
<h1>Intro</h1>
<br>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>Main part</h2>
<br>
<p>Some text</p>
```

How can I do so?

Comment: You need to try something on your own first and post the problem you are facing. There is no direct help on code writing encouraged on this site.

Comment: Ecept of your question being very superficial, I advise you to use CSS for some extra space you need after a `<h1>-` or `<h2>`-Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Node.insertAfter()` DOM function in JavaScript. But you can write your own function like the following:

```js
Object.prototype.insertAfter = function (newNode) { 
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, this.nextSibling); 
}

var header = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2');
header.forEach(function(h){
  var elBR = document.createElement('br');
  h.insertAfter(elBR);
});
```

```html
<h1>Intro</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>Main part</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `br` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses. - [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-br-element.html)

You should not use `<br>` tags for such a purpose. Instead, use the CSS `margin-bottom` property.

```html
<h1>Intro</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>Main part</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

## Using CSS

```css
h1,
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

#### Using Javscript

```js
var headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2');

headers.forEach(function(header){
  header.style.marginBottom = '30px'
});
```